# Visualforce page title

Tags: visualforce

I have a couple visualforce pages that show a title in my browser 'Documentations' that I can't figure out why.

Here's an example of one page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity"  showHeader="true" sidebar="false" title="Prospect">  


     <style>
      .activeTab {background-color: #236FBf;  color:white; background-image:none}
      .inactiveTab { background-color: white; color:black; background-image:none}
   </style>
   <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab=" tabdetails" id="OpportunityTabPanel" tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab">   


    <apex:tab label="Details" name="OpportunityDetails" id="tabdetails">
         <apex:detail relatedList="false" title="true"/>
      </apex:tab>


   <apex:tab label="Approval Process" name="Approval" id="tabApproval">
         <apex:relatedList list="ProcessSteps" ></apex:relatedList>

      </apex:tab>


       <apex:tab label="Activity History" name="Activities" id="tabActivities">
         <apex:relatedList list="activityhistories" ></apex:relatedList>

      </apex:tab>


    <apex:tab label="Chatter Feed" name="Feed" id="Feed">
          <chatter:feed entityId="{!Opportunity.Id}"/>
      </apex:tab>

    <apex:tab label="Connecitvity" name="Comm" id="Comm">
          <apex:include pageName="OppCommRoutingMDConnect"/>
      </apex:tab>

  </apex:tabPanel>
</apex:page>
```

The pic is how it shows in a browser tab. Any idea why it doesn't show my title?
[image]

Comment: Have you renamed "Opportunity" to "Documentation" in your org?

Comment: Is there any chance that this page is simply in a frame and another page is still the main page?

Comment: What API version is the page set to?

Comment: The API is 32. No, this is the main page. I am using it instead of regular view on the Opportunity page.  There is an include page in this, but it is not called Documentations.

Comment: Opportunities have not been renamed.

Comment: Did you look at the HTML of the page to see if that gives you any indication as to where it's coming from? Is there a <HEAD> and <TITLE> element in there?

Comment: do you mean view source? the first line in the code is <html class=""><head><title>Documentations ~ salesforce.com - Enterprise Edition</title>

Comment: What's the title attribute of the included page?

Comment: Hmm, there it is - Documentations. How can this override the other title?

Comment: Are you adding the visualforce page on the Opportunity Page Layout? Please explain how you have implemented this visual force page. Also, the title attribute does not work when in development mode. Have you tried to view outside of development mode?

Comment: I have set the view opportunity to redirect to this page.

Comment: My profile is not in development mode.

Comment: Switching to development mode, i see a page title of "Page Editor - OpportunityForm" OpportunityForm is the name of the Visualforce page, but not the page title, as you can see from the VF code above.

Comment: I cleared my browser cache and went out of development mode and now it calls itself "Needed Documentations" -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct dependent page and removing the title from that fixed the issue.
Sorry.
I do think it is odd that a dependent page's title will overwrite the main page's title.